# How to check GPU thread availability information in CUDA Fortran?

Tags: cuda, fortran, gpu, device

I have installed Nvidia HPC SDK 11.7 on my personal computer. I would like to check how many threads and threadblocks are available for use on my local GPU. How can I get this information?

I have read online that I should be able to run `./deviceQuery`. However I cannot find this file. In the following directory:

*path to nvhpc*/22.9/cuda/11.7/bin

I have found an executable called `__nvcc_device_query`.

When I execute this, nothing appears to happen.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. We do not put tags at the start of the question title because we have the tags here.

Comment: neither the number of threads per threadblock, nor the number of threadblocks "available", has anything to do with your GPU.  Those items are defined by CUDA.  On recent versions of CUDA, to run any of the cuda samples such as `./deviceQuery`. you must first download [the samples](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples) and build them.  The HPC SDK also requires a valid CUDA GPU and a proper GPU driver install on your machine.  If you miss any of those items, you won't be able to do much.